# How-Update-Data-In-Asp-Net-GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.LiteralControl' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox'. this error display when i update the record
 i want to update the record by datagridview by depend on the id .

```
 protected void GridView2_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(conctiioon);
    int userid = Convert.ToInt32(GridView2.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView2.Rows[e.RowIndex];
    //TextBox textName = (TextBox)row.Cells[0].Controls[0];
    TextBox textName = (TextBox)row.Cells[1].Controls[0];
    TextBox textprice = (TextBox)row.Cells[2].Controls[0];//here the error display 

    GridView2.EditIndex = -1;
    conn.Open();
    //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM detail", conn);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update items set name='" + textName.Text + "',price='" + textprice.Text + "' where id='" + userid + "'", conn);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
    gvbind();
}
```

```html
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="Id"
            OnRowDeleting="GridView2_RowDeleting" OnRowEditing="GridView2_RowEditing" OnRowUpdating="GridView2_RowUpdating"
            CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">

            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="id" HeaderText="S.No." />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="Name" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Price">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price") %>'
                            CssClass="stock">
                        </asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <a href="#" id='<%# Eval("id") %>' class="updatebutton">
                            <img border="0" src="Images/update.png" alt="Delete" />
                        </a>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:CommandField   ShowEditButton="true" />
                <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="true" />
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9E7E2" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FFFDF8" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

Comment: You are casting the cell value to textbox which is actual a literal control. In bellow line TextBox textName = (TextBox)row.Cells[1].Controls[0];

Comment: yes how can handel this

Comment: cast the name field control to literal and get the literal text like you did with textbox control.

Comment: the error display at this "textprice " how can i cast it to literal

Comment: Are you sure that error is coming while casting  cell[2] control?

Comment: yes  from this line  TextBox textprice = (TextBox)row.Cells[2].Controls[0];

Answer (score 0):

Please Means the System.Web.UI.WebControl in NameSapce(UperCase)

Answer (score 0):

I mocked your gridview and implemented a simple datasource.  You are assuming the price textbox is index 0 when there are 3 controls in that cell. The first control of that cell is not your textbox hence the cast fail.

Instead of assuming what the indexes are just find the control using the GridViewRow you already located.

```
TextBox textprice = (TextBox)(row.FindControl("TextBox1"));
```

Answer (score 0):

it will be

```
TextBox textprice = (TextBox)Gridview2.Rows[e.Rowindex].FindControl("TextBox1");
```